# scrolling ListView within ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView. One of its children is a ListView. Both scrolling in the same direction. How do I get both of them to respond to scroll events? And then when the end of the ListView is reached for the event to go to the parent ScrollView so the ScrollView may scroll?

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
... 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            .../>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/pad_half"
            >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My ListView actually goes inside the ViewPager. The design is such that about three items in the ListView is visible, and user is able to scroll to see other items. In the meantime, the views above and below the ViewPager are visible. Again, it's a ViewPager: it has other pages than the ListView in question.

Comment: "You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html Having said that, what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The scrollView has a number of children. One of them happens to be a ListView, which itself needs to scroll.

Comment: Please post your current Layout.xml

Comment: Please post your layout. You should probably reconsider it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You Should not have a listview within a ScrollView.

But you can have a custom class and use that to accomplish A Listview with in a ScrollView.

Try the following code

first make a custom ScrollView Class.

```
public class VerticalScrollview extends ScrollView{

public VerticalScrollview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

 public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                return false;

        default: break;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
     return true;
}
}
```

Then use this class for  you layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.gui.today.VerticalScrollview
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
     <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_calender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty_calender"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp" >
            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </com.gui.today.VerticalScrollview>
```

Comment: It's amazing what happens when the true expert opens his mouth. Thanks for being my wizard today. Those other negative people should learn from you. +1 and check.

Comment: This is a good answer, but if any of the other child views of the LinearLayout have a click listener, then I cannot use them to scroll the ScrollView. So basically for most of the screen, the scroll view is not scrollable. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289065/how-do-i-use-listview-as-one-of-the-children-of-a-scrollview

Answer (score 3):

> I have a ScrollView

Get rid of it.

> One of its children is a ListView

Put everything in the `ListView`, either using `addHeaderView()`/`addFooterView()`, [my `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), or something else along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You cant scroll a `listview` same direction as the `scrollview`. But if you have a horizontal `scrollview` you can scroll vertical with a `listview`.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add a ListView in a scroll View ,as list view also scolls and there would be a synchonization problem between listview scroll and scroll view scoll. You can make a CustomList View and add this method into it.

```
@Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    /*
     * Prevent parent controls from stealing our events once we've gotten a touch down
     */
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ViewParent p = getParent();
        if (p != null) {
            p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```